# PivotControl item changing behavior in Silverlight Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have an app where the user is sent to a page with a `PivotControl`. The `SelectedIndex` is not known until the user navigates to the page. I'm setting the `SelectedIndex`, but it causes the `PivotControl` to start on index 0, then flip through to the index I set.

This is kind of annoying, and I'd rather just have it go directly to the index I set. Is there some way around this?

One hack I thought up was providing the data to `pivotControl.ItemsSource` in an order such that the item I want the user to start on is index 0 in `ItemsSource`. But that would be kind of messy, and I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with the control today, sorry. Your workaround, ordering per preference, is likely the best way to achieve this for now. We're going to see if we can do better next time here!

Comment: Good to know. I'm glad that people working on the wp7 dev experience are on StackOverflow, and it's cool to hear an answer straight from someone responsible for implementing it.

Comment: Hey, I tried to implement this but I'm getting a bunch of weird bugs. Can you check out this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631529/net-argumentoutofrangeexception-when-calling-add-on-a-collection-trouble-with Thanks.